# rotations of a circle

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I do not understand what is happening in the image below.

It claims that if the rotation is irrational then every orbit will be dense. But this seems wrong.  If $\alpha=\pi/4$, for instance, then $0$ would be periodic, right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When they say "rotating by angle $\alpha$", they mean "rotating by angle $2\pi\alpha$". You can tell, because they use $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to represent the circle.

Comment: Yes... the rotation by $\pi/4$ corresponds to the (rational) value $\alpha = 1/8$, for instance.